# Как сгруппировать записи по имени и интервалу дат?

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть данные в таблице, где есть имена и даты в следующем виде:

```
Name   From       To        
------ ---------- ----------
Name 1 2021-06-07 2021-07-16
Name 1 2021-07-17 2021-07-23
Name 1 2021-07-24 2021-08-31
Name 2 2020-12-23 2021-02-19
Name 3 2021-01-22 2021-04-18
Name 3 2021-04-27 2021-05-14
Name 3 2021-05-15 2021-05-21
Name 3 2021-05-22 2021-05-28
Name 3 2021-05-29 2021-05-31
Name 4 2021-03-18 2021-04-30
Name 5 2021-07-30 2021-08-13
Name 5 2021-08-14 2021-08-20
Name 5 2021-08-21 2021-08-27
Name 5 2021-08-28 2021-09-03
Name 5 2021-09-04 2021-09-10
Name 5 2021-09-11 2021-09-24
```

В большинстве случаев для одного имени дата `To` на единицу больше даты `From` и является непрерывной, но в некоторых случаях даты прерываются.

Ожидаемый вывод должен выглядеть так:

```
Name   From       To        
------ ---------- ----------
Name 1 2021-06-07 2021-08-31
Name 2 2020-12-23 2021-02-19
Name 3 2021-01-22 2021-04-18
Name 3 2021-04-27 2021-05-31
Name 4 2021-03-18 2021-04-30
Name 5 2021-07-30 2021-09-24
```

Пробовал в запросе с `min(from)` и `max(to)`, но так теряются некоторые записи, например, для `Name 3`.

Как написать запрос, чтобы получить ожидаемые данные?

---

Тестовые данные:

```js
with t (name, date_from, date_to) as (
       select 'Name 1', date'2021-06-07', date'2021-07-16' from dual union all
       select 'Name 1', date'2021-07-17', date'2021-07-23' from dual union all
       select 'Name 1', date'2021-07-24', date'2021-08-31' from dual union all
       select 'Name 2', date'2020-12-23', date'2021-02-19' from dual union all
       select 'Name 3', date'2021-01-22', date'2021-04-18' from dual union all
       select 'Name 3', date'2021-04-27', date'2021-05-14' from dual union all
       select 'Name 3', date'2021-05-15', date'2021-05-21' from dual union all
       select 'Name 3', date'2021-05-22', date'2021-05-28' from dual union all
       select 'Name 3', date'2021-05-29', date'2021-05-31' from dual union all
       select 'Name 4', date'2021-03-18', date'2021-04-30' from dual union all
       select 'Name 5', date'2021-07-30', date'2021-08-13' from dual union all
       select 'Name 5', date'2021-08-14', date'2021-08-20' from dual union all
       select 'Name 5', date'2021-08-21', date'2021-08-27' from dual union all
       select 'Name 5', date'2021-08-28', date'2021-09-03' from dual union all
       select 'Name 5', date'2021-09-04', date'2021-09-10' from dual union all
       select 'Name 5', date'2021-09-11', date'2021-09-24' from dual
) select * from t
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Grouping data by name and date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46528442) от участника [@Auguster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1759823/auguster)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/46528442

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это можно решить с помощью, так называемого, [*Tabibitosan* метода](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/1007478/tabibitosan-method-tutorial-by-aketi-jyuuzou).

Запрос:

```sql
select name, min(date_from) date_from, max(date_to) date_to
from ( 
    select name, 
           date_from, date_to, 
           date_to - sum(date_to - date_from + 1) over (
               partition by name order by date_from) as grp
    from t)
group by name, grp
order by name, date_from
```

Результат:

```
NAME   DATE_FROM  DATE_TO   
------ ---------- ----------
Name 1 2021-06-07 2021-08-31
Name 2 2020-12-23 2021-02-19
Name 3 2021-01-22 2021-04-18
Name 3 2021-04-27 2021-05-31
Name 4 2021-03-18 2021-04-30
Name 5 2021-07-30 2021-09-24

6 rows selected.
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63981008) от участника [@mathguy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5683823/mathguy)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Начиная с версии 12.1 клауза [MATCH_RECOGNIZE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/dwhsg/sql-pattern-matching-data-warehouses.html#GUID-136DAC89-DA17-45C6-9E37-C9892723AC79) позволяет более эффективно решать подобные задачи.

Коротко, как это работает: выражение `b*` это своего рода регулярное выражение, только `b` это не одиночный символ, а запись из таблицы, отвечающая условию в `define`.

Сам запрос:

```
select name, date_from, date_to
from t
match_recognize (
    partition by name
    order by date_from
    measures 
        a.date_from as date_from,
        last (date_to) as date_to
    pattern (a b*)
    define b as date_from = prev (date_to) + 1
)
```

Результат:

```
NAME   DATE_FROM  DATE_TO   
------ ---------- ----------
Name 1 2021-06-07 2021-08-31
Name 2 2020-12-23 2021-02-19
Name 3 2021-01-22 2021-04-18
Name 3 2021-04-27 2021-05-31
Name 4 2021-03-18 2021-04-30
Name 5 2021-07-30 2021-09-24

6 rows selected.
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46529495/6571020) от участника [@mathguy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5683823/mathguy)</sub>